# How do I push code from a new local folder to an existing Github repository's main branch and keep commit history?

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

I have an existing repository in which the main branch has several commits.

I have a local folder on my desktop that contains code that I wish to commit to the main branch and completely replaces all code in the previous commit. I wish to retain the commit history of the main branch.

How do I connect my local folder to the existing github repository, point it to the main branch, commit to this branch such that it replaces all code in the previous commit and yet keeps all the commit history up to this point?

```
I have done the following:
# Initialize the local directory as a Git repository.
git init

# Add files
git add .

# Commit your changes
git commit -m "First commit"

# Add remote origin
git remote add origin <Remote repository URL>
# <Remote repository URL> looks like: https://github.com/user/repo.git

# Verifies the new remote URL
git remote -v

# Push your changes to main
git push origin main
```

But it says git error: failed to push some refs to remote

Comment: was the local folder cloned from the existing repo? or is it a new repo?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No it's completely new code that has no relation to the repo and was not cloned from it.

Comment: Have you committed the code to that local repo yet?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have updated the post with the steps I have taken. When I type git branch it currently points to a local master branch, but I would like to commit this code to the github main branch

Comment: You will likely have to merge before you can push. Whilst checked out on the local master, try `git merge origin/master --allow-unrelated-histories`. You may have to resolve conflicts

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hi the issue is that the code currently in the git main branch is substantially different from my local master code. Won't merging cause significant issues? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Just to double-check, you want to completely overwrite the code on remote's master, but preserve the commits?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I would like to completely overwrite the code on the main branch in Github, with the code currently in my remote master branch, and preserve all previous commits made to the main branch

Comment: Ok. Start again by cloning the remote repo. Delete all the code and replace it with your new code. Add. Commit. Push.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Just to clarify, do you mean clone the existing code in the main branch on github, which creates a folder. Then go into the folder and delete all the code and change it with the code i want and push?

Comment: Yes. That is my suggestion. This is because creating a new local repo complicates things. Why are you doing this btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Git is a tool, or set of tools, not a solution.](https://www.business2community.com/strategy/the-difference-between-a-tool-and-a-solution-02225199) ([Here is another article, perhaps better, on the difference.](https://zapier.com/blog/business-software-purchase-decisions/))

This has advantages.  In particular, since it *is* a set of tools, you can build almost anything you want with it.  It doesn't just turn out birdhouses, or bookcases, tables or filing cabinets, or oboes and guitars and violins, or whatever else you might be able to make in a properly equipped shop: if you know what you're doing, it can make *all* of these.  But you will need to be a master craftsman, or at least experienced, to build a good house with it—even if it's just a bird or dog house.

On the plus side, it seems that you already understand that in Git, the commits *are* the history.  This means you're off to a good start!

You will need to make one big decision up front: **How do you want the history to look?**

#### An illustration, starting with `git log`

If we look at the Git repository for Git itself, we see stuff like this (lightly edited to take out `@` signs to cut down on spam, perhaps):

```
commit eb27b338a3e71c7c4079fbac8aeae3f8fbb5c687 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 21 13:32:38 2021 -0700

    The sixth batch
    
    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>

commit fe3fec53a63a1c186452f61b0e55ac2837bf18a1
Merge: 33309e428b d1c5ae78ce
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 22 13:05:56 2021 -0700

    Merge branch 'bc/rev-list-without-commit-line'
    
    "git rev-list" learns to omit the "commit <object-name>" header
    lines from the output with the `--no-commit-header` option.
    
    * bc/rev-list-without-commit-line:
      rev-list: add option for --pretty=format without header


commit 33309e428bf85a0f06e4d23b448bf5400efe3f17
Merge: bb3a55f6d3 351bca2d1f
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 22 13:05:56 2021 -0700

    Merge branch 'ab/imap-send-read-everything-simplify'
    
    Code simplification.
    
    * ab/imap-send-read-everything-simplify:
      imap-send.c: use less verbose strbuf_fread() idiom
```

This subset of history—a small snippet of just three commits—is missing something: two of the displayed commits, `fe3fec53a63a1c186452f61b0e55ac2837bf18a1` and `33309e428bf85a0f06e4d23b448bf5400efe3f17`, are *merge commits*, each with two parent commits instead of just one.  The two parents of the middle commit `fe3fec53a63a1c186452f61b0e55ac2837bf18a1` are (abbreviated) `33309e428b` and `d1c5ae78ce`, as you can see from the first `Merge:` line in the output above.  One of those two commits is the other merge (the third commit shown), but where is commit `d1c5ae78ce`?  It's more than 40 commits down, and we can't really see *where* it lives in the history unless we add `--graph` or similar.

The *graph* option makes `git log` draw a crude ASCII-art attempt at the kind of fancy graphs you'll see in [some of the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107223/1256452) [answers to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116867/1256452) [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452) (a question, and set of answers, worth reading carefully several times, though it's quite long).  I'm particularly fond of the output from [gitdags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468472/1256452) for tutorials, though it's not at all suited to automated work (it requires careful hand construction of LaTeX input).

In the end, though, the decision *you* want to make for *your* case comes down, I think, to the answer to just one question: **Do you want a linear history, or a branch-y one?**  That is, assuming the *existing* repository has just a few commits in it that we can draw as `A-B-C-D`, we'll call your *new* commit `E`.  Do you want the history to look like:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- main (or master)
```

or do you want it to look like:

```
A--B--C--D
          \
           M   <-- main (or master)
          /
E--------’
```

?

#### In either case, you need one repository in which all the commits exist

To make this one repository in which all the commits exist, you can begin with exactly what you did already:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin <url>
```

So far, you have made the commit that we will call `E`, or a commit that looks almost exactly *like* the commit that we will call `E` eventually.  The branch name that locates this commit in *your* Git repository is almost certainly `master`; if you want this to be `main` instead, now is a good time to rename it:

```
git branch -m main
```

If you want to leave it as `master` (or if you set your Git up to use `main` so that it's already `main`<sup>1</sup>), you can leave out this step.  The actual branch name is not important (well, except to humans ... which, OK, makes it important —but the point here is that *Git* doesn't care what name you use, as long as there is some name by which to find the commit).

You *do not* yet have the A-B-C-D commits, so the next step is to obtain them:

```
git fetch origin
```

or just:

```
git fetch
```

Your Git now calls up the other Git at `origin` and obtains the existing commits (however many there really are; I'm just going to assume four, and one branch name, which I'm going to assume is `master`).  Your Git *renames* their *branch* names to make your *remote-tracking names*, by sticking `origin/` in front of each name.<sup>2</sup>

You now have, in your local repository, this:

```
E   <-- master

A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master
```

We're now ready to go on, but the *next* steps depend on whether you want a *linear* history or a *branch-y / merge-y history*.

---

<sup>1</sup>This requires a pretty modern Git, so that you can either use an argument to `git init`—that wasn't in your original quoted commands, so I am guessing you did not do this—or configure the initial branch name.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, your Git puts these remote-tracking names into an entirely separate [*namespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), so that even if you name a (local) branch `origin/foo`, *Git* won't confuse it with a renamed `foo`-from-`origin` that becomes the remote-tracking name `origin/foo`.  You'll just have two names that *display as* `origin/foo`, which will confuse the heck out of *humans*, but Git will be fine.  But don't do that, it's too confusing.

---

#### To make a merge-y history, we'll use `git merge`

Let's say you want:

```
A--B--C--D
          \
           M   <-- master
          /
         E
```

which is the same drawing I made earlier, I just slid `E` over further; we can also put `E` on the top line, and/or draw this as:

```
          E
           \
A--B--C--D--M   <-- master
```

or:

```
        E--M   <-- master
          /
A--B--C--D
```

and of course we can change the branch name from `master` to `main` to `zebra` or `zorg` or whatever, any time we like, since Git has no interest in the actual *name*.  It's just that it's a good idea to pick one and stick with it, [to avoid confusing *humans*](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/62271644/stupid-humans.jpg).

There's a hitch or two, though:

- `git merge`, since Git version 2.9, refuses to merge "unrelated histories" by default.  We can overcome this with `--allow-unrelated-histories` (assuming a Git version 2.9 or later; prior to 2.9, this option does not exist but is not required).
- Merging unrelated histories is fraught.

There's a really big escape hatch that works in our favor, though, for the latter: the `-s ours` *strategy*.<sup>3</sup>  This strategy tells Git: *completely ignore the files in the commit being merged.  Use our committed files instead.*

So:

```
git merge -s ours origin/master
```

(assuming your remote-tracking name, in your repository, is `origin/master`) produces exactly the graph we want.  Then:

```
git push -u origin master
```

works right off and sends our two new commits, `E` and `M`, to `origin`, which they add to *their* `master`, so that their `master` identifies commit `M` by its raw hash ID, just as our `master` identifies commit `M` by its raw hash ID.

(Note that the *commits* are shared.  We and they use the *same commits*, with the same hash ID.  The *branch names* are not shared: we have ours and they have theirs.  We now arrange to store the *same hash ID* into our `master` as they store into their `master`, but these are independent and will, over time, evolve independently until we deliberately synchronize them again.  Every new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, so it's always easy for two Gits to share *new* commits with each other: they always have unique hash IDs, no matter where they were made.  Two commits only have the *same* hash ID if they were already shared, and the one Git got that commit from the other Git already.)

---

<sup>3</sup>This is not to be confused with the `-X ours` *eXtended strategy option*, which won't work at all here.  The `-s` option to `git merge` supplies a strategy.  The `-X` option to `git merge` passes its argument *to* that strategy, as an option.  [The `git merge` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) calls this a *strategy-option*, which is ridiculously easy to confuse with the `-s` *strategy* option.  So I say: call it an eXtended-option, or eXtended-strategy-option.

---

#### To make a linear history, we have to work harder

If we want the history to resemble:

```
A--B--C--D--E
```

we have a problem, because we *already have commit `E`* and no part of any existing commit can ever be changed.

Commit `E`'s real hash ID, though, is some big ugly random-looking hash ID that nobody can remember, and that *only exists in our local repository* at this point.  Suppose we take our existing commit `E` and *copy* it to a slightly different, new-and-improved commit `E'` that we would draw like this:

```
E   <-- master

           E'  <-- new-master
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master
```

Now we *rename* our existing `master` to `old-master`, and our existing `new-master` to `master`:

```
E   <-- old-master

           E'  <-- master
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- origin/master
```

Then, once we're sure we like the result, we just *delete the name `old-master` entirely*.  The commit itself lingers in our repository for a while—at least 30 days by default, though this gets a bit complicated<sup>4</sup>—but eventually it goes away.  Since nobody can *remember* the old hash ID in the first place, and `git log` doesn't show it any more, we can just pretend that we never had an `E` and that `E'` is called `E`, or whatever, and this gives us a simple linear history.  I'll draw it as `E'` though:

```
A--B--C--D--E'  <-- master
```

(`origin/master` still points to `D`; I just didn't *draw* it).

We can then run `git push origin master` to add `E'` to *their* `master`, in the same way we would run `git push origin master` to add `E`-and-`M` in the branch-y case.  But we still have to make `E'` somehow.

The easiest way to do this is to use either `git commit-tree` or `git read-tree`, both of which are *plumbing* commands and rather specialized.  I'll use `git read-tree` in my example here:

```
git branch -m master old-master
git checkout -b master origin/master
git read-tree -m -u old-master
git commit -C master
git log                     # inspect the result
git push origin master      # note: `-u` not required
git branch -D old-master    # whenever you like
```

An explanation of this sequence follows; first, let's get the footnotes out of the way.

---

<sup>4</sup>The sticking-around is based on three factors.  The first two are an *object minimum lifetime*, which defaults to 14 days, and a *reflog entry lifetime*, which defaults to 30 days.  When we delete the *branch*, we delete the *branch's reflog* too.  Some consider this a bug in Git and there's a very-back-burner project, or at least idea, to change this, but it's true for now.  However, the `HEAD` name in Git has its own separate reflog, and *that* reflog will keep the commit around for 30 days from the time we made it, by default.  The third factor is that `git gc --auto`, which various Git commands run automatically for you, doesn't actually run `git gc` until Git thinks it would probably be profitable.  It's very hard to predict precisely when that will be.

---

#### Explanation

The branch rename is straightforward:

```
git branch -m master old-master
```

This renames our existing `master` to `old-master`.  (Since we're *on* `master` we could just run `git branch -m old-master`; I typed in the full command out of habit, and the above is a cut-and-paste.)

The next command is equally straightforward:

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

This creates a new `master` branch name locally, using `origin/master` as the commit hash ID.  That gives us a pointer to commit `D` (assuming four commits on `origin/master`).  As a side effect, the new `master` already has an *upstream* set, namely `origin/master`.

Now we want to get Git's *index* and our *working tree* to match commit `E`.  This is where the funky `git read-tree` command comes in:

```
git read-tree -m -u old-master
```

The `git read-tree` command is complicated and is one of Git's true workhorses, but it's very old: it implements *part of* `git merge` and *part of* `git checkout`.  Here, we're using it to run the equivalent of `git checkout`, without updating the *current branch name* at all.  A longer but clearer way to accomplish the same thing is to use `git rm -rf .` to remove every file, followed by `git checkout old-master -- .` to repopulate Git's index and our working tree.  Should `git read-tree` ever vanish, that would be a way to do what we want.  (Another would be to use `git checkout` followed by `git symbolic-ref`, and yet another would be to use `git commit-tree` followed by `git reset` or `git merge --ff-only`: there are many tools in this workshop that will get you from point A to point B.)

The `git commit` we use is pretty much the normal `git commit`, with just one option added, namely `-C old-master`:

```
git commit -C old-master
```

The `-C` option tells Git to take the *commit message* from the specified commit.  Here, we point `git commit` to existing commit `E` to grab the commit message.  You can leave out the `-C` option and just type in an all-new commit message, if you like.

The final `git push` is like any `git push`, but because we created our `master` with its upstream already set to `origin/master`, we don't need the `-u` option that we needed in the branch-y / merge-y construction.

#### Which is better: linear history or branchy/mergy?

Which is better, chocolate ice cream, or strawberry?  Which is better, learning to fly kites, or learning to fly helicopters?  It's partly a matter of opinion and partly a matter of where you want to go and how you want to get there, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: This is super in-depth, thank you for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 2):

First of all do a git clone in new folder, this will copy all got repository to local machine and will make it a local repository. Now copy paste your new folders in that local repository, this will override folders downloaded from git. Now do a git add. Then say git commit and git push.

Comment: Would pulling help when the histories are unrelated? Won't it throw an error?

Comment: Edited it to git clone. When you will do git clone it will also create a folder named as .git and then when you will again commit after overriding folders it will remember history.